# change graph attributes in python

Tags: python-3.x, igraph

I am having trouble changing the attribute of a particular vertex in a graph object in `igraph`.

```
from igraph import *
G = Graph()
G.add_vertices(2)
G.vs['names'] = [(1, 1), (10, 10)]

# change the name
G.vs['names'][0] = (5, 5)
print G.vs['names'][0]
(1, 1)
```

I tried changing the tuples to lists, but it did not work

```
G = Graph()
G.add_vertices(2)
G.vs['names'] = [ [1, 1], [10, 10] ]
G.vs['names'][0] = [5, 5]
print G.vs['names'][0]
[1, 1]
```

I tried to also use `G.vs['position'][0].pop()`, and it did not work either. Any idea how I might be able to change the attributes in igraph?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the issue was that I was using:

```
G.vs["position"][0] = [5, 5]
```

and I needed to use this instead:

```
G.vs[0]["position"] = [5, 5]
```

This fixed it, thanks!